# Comparing two columns on a row and removing if they match

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm looking to create a report in iReport, this will display a row of Car weights which includes there expected weight and actual weight. I'm looking to only display the cars that have are different between the actual weight and expected weight. I'm also looking to display an extra columns on the right which displays how much they're different by.

E.g.

```
CAR         Expected Weight           ActualWeight           WeightDIFF
-------------------------------------------

> NUGLN9L       2000kg                    2200kg      200kg

> YBOL9GT        1700kg                   1700kg      0kg (Shouldn't display this row)

> CL55GBP        1100kg                   2200kg      1100kg
```

The part of *jrxml*:

```
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="108" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="205a44be-528a-4d6b-83e7-85cc0f417fd6"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{car}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="219" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="704e546a-d4f1-4d8d-b5e7-a7ac8154d882"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{expectedWeight}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="332" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="08846a54-7415-4f32-a0ef-41f2770e2278"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ActualWeight}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="443" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="7ebea114-3303-48c0-b877-f0940c62aa7f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{WeightDIFF}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
```

Any help would be excellent

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AlexK it's basically how do I return only rows that have different weights. I'm also potentially going to create another columns which will show you the weight difference if there is one.

Comment: You can use "Print when expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using iReport designer you can select the field on screen, on the right pane of properties each field has a Print When Expression property. You can create a variable (Boolean is easiest). E.G

```
!$F{CarWeight1}.equals($F{CarWeight2})
```

Create a variable and set that as a boolean. Drop the variable into the print when expression property on each field. Also worth ticking remove line when blank for each field for formatting purposes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As @AlexK pointed out, you can use the `Print when` expression.

After your `<band>` row, add the following (I assume $F{WeightDIFF} is an `Integer`):

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{WeightDIFF} > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
```